# What is a singular space in relation to differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I'm reading a paper and it references geodesics on singular spaces and I can't find a good definition for this.

Could someone provide a good definition?

Comment: Depending on the context, a geodesic is either a local or global isometric embedding of an interval .

Comment: I'm asking for the definition of a singular space not of a geodesic.

Comment: then you should edit your question. As for singular spaces, different authors have different definitions in mind.

Answer (score 2):

From what you wrote, all one can say that it is a metric space which is not a Riemannian manifold with its distance function. Anything else is context dependent. Some authors mean an Alexandrov space , some mean a  Riemannian metric with conical singularities , some mean a piecewise Riemannian cell complex ....

**Edit.** In the context of the paper you linked to, a singular submanifold is a real-analytic subset $M$ of $R^n$ equipped with the restriction of a Riemannian metric (you can even assume the standard one) from $R^n$ to $M$. The restricted Riemannian metric is singular at the singular points of $M$. The authors provide references (Lytchak, Mazzeo, et al.) for the detailed definitions, in their paper they consider a very special class of singularities, the cuspidal ones.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Here's the specific paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4554

Comment: The specific line is at the beginning of the second page.  "Much less is known about the behavior of geodesics on singular spaces."